# Docker Push image(12GB) to private docker hub repo restarts or times out

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I created a Docker image in my ubuntu VM machine

Dockerfile:

```
FROM kubevirt/container-disk-v1alpha
ADD win8.1pro.qcow2 /disk
```

I logged in to my tcl1 docker hub registry and ran `docker build -t tcl1/win8.1pro:latest -f Dockerfile .`

when pushing the win 8.1pro image to tcl1 (in my case 12GB) the push times out and/or Restarts around 20MB.

I tried this different networks, Different VMs/Baremetal VMs, still same results. There is no blocker from the network side/or any firewalls.

I tried pushing random 1gb image and it got pushed but large images pushing times out at 20Mb out of 12GB but the same 12gbn image can be pushed to a local registry running in a container.